# Best way to handle multiple python projects in one directory?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a main directory:

```
main/
|
|---- requirements.txt # requirements for ALL python subprojects
|--- PythonProject1/
|--- PythonProject2/
|--- PythonProject3/
```

So there are 3 python projects under `main/`.
The thing I want to do is have only one `requirements.txt` file so that the sub-projects dont have to have dependency management on their own.

I am wondering what the **best** way to accomplish this is? Is having `main/requirements.txt` good enough? Or is this not ideal?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a Docker Images for your projects if you have the relevant experience.

This way you can easily share your image with your co-workers without having to maintain a requirements.txt file.

It is quite easy to install [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

After installation, you can either (1) build via a DockerFile or (2) pull-down official Images from [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/)

```
(1) docker build -t project1 .
(2) docker pull [Official_Image_name_from_Docker_Hub]
```

**IF new** Run these commands from CLI after starting Docker.

```
docker container ls -a --will get you recent containers
docker image ls --will get you all your images
docker run hello-world --run this to get an image pulled + run
```

Once you create your base image you can run it as a container after mounting a volume as

```
docker run -it -v "%cd%":/data [yourImageName] bash
```

After completing your projects you can commit these containers as new Images and push them onto Docker Hub, which can be pulled down by your team members.

```
docker commit [containerID/Name] [newImageName]:[TAG]
docker push [newImageName]:[TAG]
```

Comment: Thanks! so the idea is that the base docker image will contain all of the dependencies that coworkers can use? How does this work for `pip3` dependencies?

Comment: Yes, An Image is basically downloaded software (OS, python libraries, etc) So once you have this Image created you can push it to Docker Hub and run it anytime as a container anywhere, that already has the required OS, Libraries, dependencies, etc

Comment: I think I run into the same issue that I am having now.

Say I want to add a new job with new dependencies so I have to edit that docker image now. The main point is that I only wanted one source of truth for dependencies if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, so you avoid the step of having to maintain those requirements.txt files, Once you **pip install** your packages after creating a new project and commit that running container as a new latest version of the Image, it will always have those new dependencies.